# Inserting a value one at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a table that holds form details, the form num(identity column) and the 5 columns for the Questions Score.

My insert proc for the form is very basic:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Insert_New_Form]
      @questionOne int, @questionTwo int, @questionThree int,
      @questionFour int, @questionFive Int  as 
begin 
     Insert into Questionire_Form values ( 
         @questionOne, @questionTwo, @questionThree, 
         @questionFour, @questionFive) 
end
```

and I hold an int call answer that it's value changes between radio button selection (scoring).

My question is, how do I write a procedure to insert all of the answers in one row, meaning at each click on "next" button the score for the specific answer will be inserted to the row at the specific column.

and how do I wirte the update procedure should I use chack again button to go through the form?

I am using MS SQL 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the following code will help you

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_Score
 @userID         INT
 @questionNumber INT,
 @score          INT
AS
    DECLARE @ColumnaName VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @sql         VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @ColumnName = 
    ( CASE @questionNumber
        WHEN 1 THEN 'ColumnOne'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'ColumnTwo'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'ColumnThree'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'ColumnFour'
      END )

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Questionire_Form WHERE UserID = @userID) THEN
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'UPDATE Questionire_Form SET ' + @ColumnName + ' = ' + @score + ' WHERE UserID = ' + @userID
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO Questionire_Form (UserID, ' + @ColumnName + ') VALUES(' + @userID + ', ' + @score + ')'
    END

    EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks that helps alot! I just need a hint how to apply this on the code behind using SqlConnection and SqlCommand